# mongoose optimistic concurrency - how to track changes on document when versioning error handling is needed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

we have a big enterprise Node.JS application with multiple microservices that can in parallel access DB entity called context. At some moment we started to have concurrency issues, i.e. two separate microservices did load same context, did different changes and saved, resulting in loss of data. Because of this we have rewritten our DB layer to use mongoose with full optimistic  concurrency enabled (via scheme option *optimisticConcurrency*). This work fine and now when we get version error we reload latest version of the context, **reapply** all the changes again and save. Problem is that this reapplication creates duplicities in code. Our general approach can be expressed by following pseudo code:

```
let document = Context.find(...);
document.foo = 'bar'
document.bar = 'foo'

try  {
    document.save()
} catch(mongooseVersionError) {
    let document = Context.find(...);
    // DUPLICATE CODE HERE, DOING SAME ASSIGNMENTS (foo, bar) AGAIN!        
    document.foo = 'bar'
    document.bar = 'foo'
    document.save()
}
```

What we would like to use instead is some automated tracking of all changes on document so that when we get mongoose versioning error we can reapply these changes automatically. Any idea how to do it in most elegant way? Does mongoose support something like this out of the box? I know that we could check in presave hook document attributes one by one via ***Document.prototype.isModified()*** method but this seems to me like quite worky and unflexible approach.